# Empty space between background-color and border-radius

Tags: html, css

I saw some white space between green background-color and border-radius (especially when I zoom-in).

Is there any fix?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPjgJZ

```css
.container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;

  background-color: antiquewhite;

  border: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>HeaderText</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.container`
2. Give `border-radius:34px 34px 0 0;` to `.header`

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.header {
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 34px 34px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>HeaderText</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this method but I'm afraid it's a good practice. Is there any connection between value of external and internal border-radius? or I should try different values to fit empty space?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the reason is, but I just change `background-color` color-block to `linear-gradient`in parent's css to make sure the background's color on 15% height parent has same color with the header. So there is no any white-space anymore.

```css
.container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, 15%, antiquewhite 15%);
}

.header{
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>HeaderText</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023: you can now use

```
overflow: clip;
overflow-clip-margin: 1px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-clip-margin

This way the content will go a bit further and be hidden under the border of the container, instead of being clipped a bit before the border and causing the space to appear.