# Getting Div inside Div to align to display with rounded corners

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code (using react with inline styling) used to display a custom modal. for the "title" bar at the top that says "Deactivate phone number", I can't seem to get it to render cleanly, without showing some white space between the divs. Notice in the picture, the white at top, and on left side of title bar. I've tried setting border of title div to 0, set outline:'none', but nothing renders cleanly.

How can I get this to cleanly show top bar?

```
  <div
          style={{
            width: width,
            height: height,
            border: '1px solid #E06055',
            overflow:'hidden',
            backgroundColor: `white`,
            borderRadius: '20px',
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#E06055',
              textAlign: 'center',
              color: 'white',
              outline:'none',
              verticalAlign: 'center',
              height: '40px',
              fontSize: '20px',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
          >
            <Icon path={mdiAlert} size="20px" color="white" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} />
            {title}
          </div>
         <div>CONTENT</div>
      </div>
```

[image]

I've just simplified this to a simple div inside a div where the top div uses a boarder without any border radius. and it still appears. There has to be a way where you can have top div have border and remove that whitespace?

```
 <div style={{height:'400px',width:'300px', backgroundColor:'white', border:'1px solid red'}}>
      <div style={{height:'40px', backgroundColor:'red', color:'white'}}>
          Top bar
      </div>
      <div>
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty space between background-color and border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989391/empty-space-between-background-color-and-border-radius)

Comment: I've tried those solutions, it doesn't remove the white space.